# Analyze all garbage in memory by jprofile

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jprofiler

I am tuning Java performance by Jprofiler. The gc is frequent. I guess maybe there are too many unnecessary memory allocations. Any idea to find out certainly all untouchable object that would destroy by garbage collection?

Using allocate hotspot can indicate which object has been created frequently, but it is uncertain whether it's really a garbage object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the allocation hot spots and call tree view, you can set the "Liveness mode" to "Garbage collected objects". Then you will only see objects that have been GCed.

[image]